# Convert BindingSource to Datatable or Dataset

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using data binding source which datasource bind with list. Now I converting this datasource to dataset but it throw up the exception like:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'

I am writing this code to convert datasource to dataset.

```
 if (childCtrl is DataGridView)
                    {
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds = (DataSet)(((DataGridView)childCtrl).DataSource);
                        ds.WriteXml(@"D:\AverageReporting.xml");
                    }
```

So there is any possible way to converting binding source data to dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
 ds.table[0].Columns.Add(col.HeaderText, typof(string));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
  {
      ds.table[0].Rows[row.Index][cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;   
  }          
}
```